# Getting user locale information in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, user, user-management, locale, languagelocalekey

In Aura, we can get the user locale info by using $A.get("$Locale.langLocale"). What is the equivalent in LWC ? Searched in developer doc and in google, not able to find it. How to get the locale language info in LWC.

Thanks.

Comment: Does https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_i18n help?

Comment: Not exactly. tried using those, but not  working

Comment: You may want to add more details to your question about what is not working, because the `@salesforce/i18n/locale` module is the LWC equivalent of `$A.get("$Locale.langLocale")`.

Answer (score -2):

you can import those library  in lwc

import LOCALE from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';

Comment: Hi jeevi, does it provide the user's local language ?
what does '@salesforce/i18n/lang' do ?